# How to create a simple two table schema with TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a schema with two tables and will later query/add data to them. I am using the StackExchange Data Explorer "T-SQL": https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Here are the requirements:

**Customer** table:

```
    unique account id, 
    Fname
    Lname 
    create date
```

**CustomerStatus** table (`status` will say pending, active, or cancelled):

```
    unique record id
    unique account id 
    string value named Status, 
    create date
```

Other requirements:

- tables contain primary keys
- auto incrementing identifiers
- indicates columns that should not be null
- have proper data types for the columns

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
(
   ID INT NOT NULL,
   FNAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
   LNAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE CustomerStatus
(
   recordID INT NOT NULL,
   ID INT NOT NULL,
   STATUS VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I create the two table schema.  At the bottom is what I have so far.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You apparently have the tables - or at least the `create table` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do that on [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).

Try [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler) or [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk).

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/MOH19608

```
create table Customers(
   id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
   fname varchar (20) not null,
   lname varchar (20) not null,
);

create table CustomerStatus(
   recordid int not null identity(1,1),
   id int not null references Customers(id),
   [status] varchar (10) not null,
);
```